# Javascript/web dev: Why do you need a server to connect to hardware?

Tags: javascript, web, arduino

Many JS applications are client side. But if I wanted to interface with an Arduino, I would need to do so over a server using something like Node.js. Why is this?

Comment: elaborate please, What is you wanna know ?
node.js is written in c/c++ it is NOT vanilla javascript, which leaves the former for the client side

Comment: Okay, here's my situation (and bare with me because I know nothing): I'm interfacing with an arduino using p5.js, but it requires me to install node so it can be run on a server. Why is it that if I am working with hardware I/O I need to run it on a server, but if I am doing just basic JS web scripting (like drawing a circle) I can run everything locally without a server?

Comment: Usually you communicate with an Arduino through a comm port. JS in a web page can't access the ports. So, you run a server that can.

Comment: So if I were to put this online, does that mean that users would have to run their own local servers to interface with the Arduino?

Comment: @NullSalad Please put that comment into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security and cross-plattform reasons, a web application is limited to a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)). Originally, web applications could just request URLs to load, handle keyboard/mouse input when they are focused, and control the display in their window.

Anything else depends on an additional API that the browser has to offer, so the default state is nothing more. Again, for security reasons the operating system's APIs are not accessible from web applications.

So why don't current browsers have an API for accessing Arduinos? Apart from [every feature starting at -100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/), the reason is that it's quite hard to allow such access to USB devices without compromising security (for example avoiding a web application to read your USB keyboard inputs and thus capture all future passwords, or overheat your [foot warmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AC8UQVS)).

Fortunately, such a standard is currently being developed - it's called [**WebUSB**](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/). However, no browser supports it by default as of May 2016, although you [can enable it in Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5651917954875392) by changing the value of `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`.

Comment: Note that a totally different way of using JavaScript for device control is via Node.js, as the OP notes. That approach avoids browser issues entirely.